# change geotiff data to lat lon python

Tags: python, gis, geotiff, rasterio

Hello I have obtained a geotiff with flood risk data, I need to show on map and also get it values querying lat,lon.

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show
raster = rasterio.open('/content/geonode_fp_flood_category.tif')
show(raster) #show image
raster.profile #show profile
```

[image]

Opening the file in python with rasterio give me this information raster.profile:

```
{'driver': 'GTiff', 'dtype': 'int16', 'nodata': -32768.0, 'width': 2952, 'height': 4070, 'count': 1, 'crs': CRS.from_epsg(32616), 'transform': Affine(90.98088343224933, 0.0, 255612.775997,
   0.0, -90.98088343243249, 2052554.35523), 'tiled': False, 'interleave': 'band'}
```

I know the data  is not in the desired lat,lon projection but I cannot find the way to generate a new geotiff in that coordinate system  (lat,lon) or if rasterio is the right tool for this. Thanks for any help

Comment: From `epsg.io`, the projection is 
WGS 84 / UTM zone 16N - EPSG:32616

Comment: you can use rasterio to reproject the tif from ESPG:32616 to ESPG:4326 (wgs84). see https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reproject.html